# Ubuntu only old version of cuda being detected

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables, cuda

I am currently using a university GPU, for which I don't have root permissions. I was told to add a directory to my `.bashrc` file so that I could use `cuda 8` and `cudnn 6`. I have done this, when installing the theano-gpu environment. However, now when I run `which nvcc` or check which version of `cuda` or `cudnn` is installed, I get `cuda` version 7.5 and an older `cudnn` (I'm assuming an older `cudnn` because of the output of `check libcudnn`, but I'm not sure if it's showing `cudnn 6`).

Terminal outputs:

```
raviteja@puck:~$ which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc

raviteja@puck:~$ check libcudnn 
    libcudnn.so.4 -> libcudnn.so.4.0.7
    libcudnn.so.5 -> libcudnn.so.5.1.3
libcudnn is installed

raviteja@puck:~$ echo $PATH
/home/mixqui/raviteja/virtenvs/homography/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0:/usr/local/cuda-8.0:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cudnn6.0/lib64:/usr/local/cudnn5.1/lib64:/usr/local/cudnn4.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64::/usr/local/cudnn6.0/include::/usr/local/cudnn6.0/lib64:/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv/lib:/bin:/home/mixqui/raviteja/IDE/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin:/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv:/home/mixqui/raviteja/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

How come `cuda 8` and `cudnn 6` aren't being detected, even though they are at the start of my `$PATH` environment variable? How can I fix this?

Edit:

After trying out the below answer, my .bashrc file is as follows:

```
#where to store the virtual envs
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/virtenvs
#where the projects will reside
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Projects-Active
#where is the virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# set PATH for cuda 8.0 installation
if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/" ]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi

export PATH=/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv:~/anaconda/bin:$PATH

export THEANO_FLAGS='cuda.root=/usr/local/cuda-8.0,device=cuda0,floatX=float32'
export CUDA_ROOT='/usr/local/cuda-8.0'
export CUDA_HOME='/usr/local/cuda-8.0'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cudnn6.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/usr/local/cudnn6.0/include:$CPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cudnn6.0/lib64:/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=~/IDE/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}:${CUDA_ROOT}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${CPATH}:${LIBRARY_PATH}/bin:${PATH}

export CPATH=~/.local/include:/usr/local/lib:$CPATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/lib:/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:~/.local/lib:/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/mixqui/raviteja/opencv/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

However, even after I execute `source .bashrc`, the output of `nvcc --version` hasn't changed:

```
raviteja@puck:~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Comment: It's `nvcc -V` or `nvcc --version` for the version check of `nvcc`.  `which` command shows you which one it finds in the path.   For  the cudnn try something like `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2` where you change cuda to match your installation.

Comment: `nvcc --version` shows this: `nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
`

Comment: Hopefully the systems administrator installed CUDA 8.0 correctly, so all you should have to do is what I answered below.

Comment: I deleted my answer.  You need to restore what you have done and you need to copy what other users have done or ask your systems administrator to give you the info.  We cannot help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this system is controlled by a systems administrator that others have working and OP needs to copy their file.